# React Countdown using setInterval

Tags: reactjs, timer, setinterval, react-hooks, countdowntimer

I made this countdown component with setInterval, the problem I'm facing is when there is more than 1 instance of the component on the page, only the first component works as intended.
When the second component reaches to 0 seconds he runs the "subtractSeconds" function twice for some reason.
I can't figure out what exactly I'm doing wrong. 
Here is a codesandbox link of the code

https://codesandbox.io/s/timer-example-fyy5v

Comment: both seem to be working fine in the sandbox

Comment: @richbai90 please notice that the second timer is set to 2 hours, and after one second it is changing to 00:58 minutes